# HOW TO initialize data in back4app column of a class to be use inside flutter

Tags: function, parse-platform, future, void, back4app

So I have a parse data from back app. let just take easy, from class User, I made a column of name. which is Ricky.
now I want to use this column when I access a page under variables of _name. so it will appear on my flutter screen

Hi, (column name of current user from class User)

code

```
Text('Hai, $_nama',textAlign: TextAlign.start,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
```

so it appear as

Hi, Ricky

anyone can help how to code this?

I know most function to called those User column use ParseObject and/or ParseUser and it is always have Future/void type.

code on calling parse column

```
class UserAccess {


  Future<String> namaLengkap() async {
    ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser() as ParseUser;
    String nl = await currentUser.get('NamaLengkap');
    return nl;
  }
}
```

this is where I access the function (do note I do not post the import)

```
class Home2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home2State createState() => _Home2State();
}

class _Home2State extends State<Home2> {
  String _nama;
  bool _usaha;


  showFailedBusinessDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Widget okButton = ElevatedButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pop();},
    );
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      content: Text("Anda harus mendaftarkan\nusaha anda dahulu!"),
      actions: [
        okButton,
      ],
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer.run(() async {
      final _nama = await UserAccess().namaLengkap();
      return _nama;
    });
    Timer.run(() async {
      _usaha = await UserAccess().AdaUsaha();
      return _usaha;
    });
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Daur.id'),
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 48.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          shadowColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
          elevation: 5.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bell_fill, color: Colors.black,), onPressed: (){
              pushNewScreen(
                context,
                screen: Notifikasi(),
                withNavBar: false,
                pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
              );
            })
          ],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/background1.jpeg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover
                  )
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 10.0, 15.0, 40.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,child: Text('Hai, $_nama',textAlign: TextAlign.start,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                            Text('Mari kita bersihkan sampah dari lingkungan',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),)
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
                        ImagePickerWidget(
                          diameter: 60,
                          initialImage: "https://apprecs.org/gp/images/app-icons/300/81/com.unzypsoft.rekeningbookapps2.jpg" ,
                          shape: ImagePickerWidgetShape.circle,
                          isEditable: false,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            blurRadius: 10.0,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2)
                        )],),
                      height: 120.0,
                      width: 400.0,
                      child: Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          shadowColor: Colors.black,
                          toolbarHeight: 30.0,
                          title: Text('D Points',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                        ),
                        body: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(height:5.0,),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                IconButton(iconSize: 50.0,icon: Icon(Icons.add_comment_outlined), onPressed: (){
                                  pushNewScreen(
                                    context,
                                    screen: OrderIndividu(),
                                    withNavBar: false,
                                    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                                  );
                                }),
                                SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
                                IconButton(iconSize: 50.0,icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_return_outlined), onPressed: (){}),
                                SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
                                IconButton(iconSize: 50.0,icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline), onPressed: (){
                                  if(_usaha == true){
                                    pushNewScreen(
                                      context,
                                      screen: OrderUsaha(),
                                      withNavBar: false,
                                      pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                                    );
                                  } else{
                                    showFailedBusinessDialog(context);
                                  };
                                }),
                                SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
                                IconButton(iconSize: 50.0,icon: Icon(Icons.redeem_sharp), onPressed: (){}),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(width: 24.0,),
                                Text('Top Up'),
                                SizedBox(width: 57.0,),
                                Text('Share'),
                                SizedBox(width: 57.0,),
                                Text('Usaha'),
                                SizedBox(width: 50.0,),
                                Text('Redeem')
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cube_box_fill, size: 50.0,color: Colors.green,), onPressed: (){}),
                        SizedBox(width: 40.0,),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bus, size: 50.0,color: Colors.blue,), onPressed: (){}),
                        SizedBox(width: 40.0,),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bag_fill, size: 50.0,color: Colors.orange,), onPressed: (){
                          pushNewScreen(
                            context,
                            screen: DaftarUsahaFront(),
                            withNavBar: false,
                            pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                          );
                        }),
                        SizedBox(width: 40.0,),
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.archivebox_fill, size: 50.0,color: Colors.red,), onPressed: (){}),
                        SizedBox(width: 40.0,),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(width: 35.0,),
                        Text('PickUp'),
                        SizedBox(width: 35.0,),
                        Text('Drop Off'),
                        SizedBox(width: 40.0,),
                        Text('Usaha'),
                        SizedBox(width: 55.0,),
                        Text('Event'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    // 3 BOX KOSONG SEMENTARA AJA
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    // CarouselSlider(items: items, options: options),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: 100.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: 100.0,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    // ISI KOTAK INI CONG
                    Container(
                      height: 350.0,
                      width: 400.0,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            blurRadius: 10.0,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2)
                        )],),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Statistik Daur Ulang', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          Text('Kamu hebat, berikut hasil usaha daur ulangmu \nbersama Mall Daur!',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0), ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Kertas'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Kaca'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Elektronik'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Besi dan Logam'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.purple,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Plastik'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.brown,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Alumunium'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Fabric/Baju'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Kayu'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 7.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.cyan,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Bio'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Container(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 170.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                                  )],),
                                child: Text('Mix'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the problem that you currently have. your var n1 should have the data you want.

Comment: that nl would take _nama = nl .. in which should have been appear on my text file I above, but it is only appears as Hi, Null, instead Hi, Ricky

Comment: You are probably not awaiting for `namaLengkap` to complete before calling the `Text` function. If you want to share how those things work together, maybe someone can try to help.

Comment: than can you help how to initialize future function and making sure it FINISH that function and point that on UI result?

Comment: I'd do something like `final _name = await namaLengkap();`

Comment: still appears as Null

Comment: Could you update the question with your current code showing how the two pieces of code join together?

Comment: already edit the post, please see it

Comment: I believe the problem happens when you do `final _nama = await UserAccess().namaLengkap();`. It is actually creating a new _nama var in the function local scope instead of using the class attribute. Try to change it to `_nama = await UserAccess().namaLengkap();`

Comment: unfortunately. it still suffer the same thing.. I already try to remove `final` from those function and also remove `return _nama` it will still appear as `Hi, Null` when I made hot restart, however the funniest thing if I just made plain `ctrl+s` it will make as `Hi, Ricky Des Safry` which is problematic for the final product as I want those appear as a name instead null when application start